# How to upload a file to OneDrive using REST API using a C# Application?

Tags: onedrive

We are trying to upload a file to OneDrive using REST API using a C# Application, but we are unable to create an Authentication token that is required for submitting the file upload. We have tried one drive functionality using documentation and some reference links we got from google search but nothing seems to be working.

Thank you.

Comment: Providing some examples on how it didn't work and what you actually tried would likely get better answers, as ATM your question is extremely broad and difficult to answer. That being said, try going through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online) about the authentication flow when dealing with Onedrive...

Comment: I'm trying to uploading a file to one drive using a C# console application. When I try to request an access token, I'm getting a sign-in page as a response. Please find the below code

Comment: string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=myclientidhere&scope=files.readwrite.all&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

request.Method = "GET";

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
}

Reference Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Can you edit the question and add this so it's properly formatted?